# Oracle SQL SELECT SUM when a value is different with other GROUP BY clauses

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sum, oracle12c

I have the following sample_data dataset :

```
ORD |   POS   | INSGRP | INS |   DELI    |   DELPOS
-------------------------------------------------------
1   | 'Pos11' | '11'   | 11  | 'deli111' | 'DelPos1111'
1   | 'Pos11' | '11'   | 11  | 'deli112' | 'DelPos1121'
1   | 'Pos11' | '11'   | 11  | 'deli112' | 'DelPos1122'

2   | 'Pos21' | '21'   | 21  | 'deli211' | 'DelPos2111'
2   | 'Pos21' | '22'   | 22  | 'deli221' | 'DelPos2211'
2   | 'Pos21' | '22'   | 22  | 'deli221' | 'DelPos2212'

3   | 'Pos31' | '31'   | 31  | 'deli311' | 'DelPos3111'
3   | 'Pos32' | '31'   | 31  | 'deli321' | 'DelPos3211'
3   | 'Pos32' | '31'   | 31  | 'deli321' | 'DelPos3212'
3   | 'Pos32' | '31'   | 31  | 'deli322' | 'DelPos3221'
```

- When there are many POS for an ORD, there's only one INSGRP
- When there's only one POS for an ORD, there can be many INSGRP
- This is a simple version of my actual request that only expose this problem
- One ORD can have many DELI
- One DELI can have many DELPOS
- DELI and DELPOS are there to add rows that duplicate ORD-POS-INSGRP-INS

I want to SUM the INS column depending on ORD, POS and INSGRP.

- When there's only one INSGRP for a POS, I want INS to stay the same.
- When there are many INSGRP for a POS, I want the SUM of INS of the different INSGRP for that POS

So I want the following result :

```
ORD | SUM(INS)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 11
One INSGRP for one POS, so INS stay the same 11
2   | 43
Two INSGRP for one POS, so INS is the SUM of the INSGRP 21 and 22 so 43 
3   | 31
One INSGRP for two POS, so INS stay the same 31
```

I tried the following :

```
SELECT ord,
       SUM (ins) AS ins
FROM sample_data
GROUP BY ord, pos
ORDER BY ord;
```

And got this result :

```
ORD | INS
---------
1   | 33
2   | 65
3   | 31
3   | 93
```

Everything is summed and there's a row for each INSGRP of ORD 3. I then added INS to the GROUP BY clause, but it only separated ORD 2 on two lines.

I tried grouping with everything and putting a UNIQUE at the beginning :

```
SELECT UNIQUE ord,
       SUM (ins) AS ins
FROM sample_data
GROUP BY ord, pos, deli, DelPos
ORDER BY ord;
```

And the result was :

```
ORD | INS
---------
1   | 11
2   | 21
2   | 22
3   | 31
```

That's the closest I got from the result I want. The only missing part is to group ORD 2 on one line and SUM the INS.

Also, I want to be able to partition the group like :

```
SUM (ins) OVER (PARTITION BY ord, pos, deli, DelPos) AS ins
```

Can someone help me with this?

---

Here's the request whit sample_data :

```
WITH sample_data
     AS (SELECT 1 ord, 'Pos11' pos, '11' insGrp, 11 ins, 'deli111' deli, 'DelPos1111' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 ord, 'Pos11' pos, '11' insGrp, 11 ins, 'deli112' deli, 'DelPos1121' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 ord, 'Pos11' pos, '11' insGrp, 11 ins, 'deli112' deli, 'DelPos1122' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL

         SELECT 2 ord, 'Pos21' pos, '21' insGrp, 21 ins, 'deli211' deli, 'DelPos2111' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 ord, 'Pos21' pos, '22' insGrp, 22 ins, 'deli221' deli, 'DelPos2211' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 ord, 'Pos21' pos, '22' insGrp, 22 ins, 'deli221' deli, 'DelPos2212' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL

         SELECT 3 ord, 'Pos31' pos, '31' insGrp, 31 ins, 'deli311' deli, 'DelPos3111' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 ord, 'Pos32' pos, '31' insGrp, 31 ins, 'deli321' deli, 'DelPos3211' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 ord, 'Pos32' pos, '31' insGrp, 31 ins, 'deli321' deli, 'DelPos3212' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 ord, 'Pos32' pos, '31' insGrp, 31 ins, 'deli322' deli, 'DelPos3221' DelPos FROM DUAL)
SELECT UNIQUE ord,
     SUM (ins) AS ins
FROM sample_data
GROUP BY ord, pos, deli, DelPos
ORDER BY ord;
```

Or the create and insert

```
create table tbl (ord number, pos varchar2(10),  insGrp varchar2(10), ins number, deli varchar2(10), DelPos varchar2(10))

insert into tbl (SELECT 1 ord, 'Pos11' pos, '11' insGrp, 11 ins, 'deli111' deli, 'DelPos1111' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 ord, 'Pos11' pos, '11' insGrp, 11 ins, 'deli112' deli, 'DelPos1121' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 ord, 'Pos11' pos, '11' insGrp, 11 ins, 'deli112' deli, 'DelPos1122' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL

         SELECT 2 ord, 'Pos21' pos, '21' insGrp, 21 ins, 'deli211' deli, 'DelPos2111' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 ord, 'Pos21' pos, '22' insGrp, 22 ins, 'deli221' deli, 'DelPos2211' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 ord, 'Pos21' pos, '22' insGrp, 22 ins, 'deli221' deli, 'DelPos2212' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL

         SELECT 3 ord, 'Pos31' pos, '31' insGrp, 31 ins, 'deli311' deli, 'DelPos3111' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 ord, 'Pos32' pos, '31' insGrp, 31 ins, 'deli321' deli, 'DelPos3211' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 ord, 'Pos32' pos, '31' insGrp, 31 ins, 'deli321' deli, 'DelPos3212' DelPos FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 ord, 'Pos32' pos, '31' insGrp, 31 ins, 'deli322' deli, 'DelPos3221' DelPos FROM DUAL)
```

Comment: Could you share the CREATE scripts and provide some sample data in the form of INSERT statements?

Comment: What do you mean by "Also, I want to be able to partition ..."? Isn't a GROUP BY enough? Could you show expected output given your sample data?

Comment: Like I said, this is a simple test, in my final request I want others fields GROUP BY different column. So I can't GROUP BY the entire SELECT. The expected result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT ord,
     CASE WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT pos) = 1 THEN SUM(DISTINCT ins) ELSE MIN(ins) END AS ins
FROM sample_data
GROUP BY ord
ORDER BY ord;

ORD INS   
--- ------
  1     11
  2     43
  3     31
```

Comment: Nice thank you! I adjusted it with PARTITION and it works great!
    
CASE WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT pos) OVER (PARTITION BY ord) = 1 THEN SUM(DISTINCT ins) OVER (PARTITION BY ord) ELSE MIN(ins) OVER (PARTITION BY ord) END AS ins